# Tried Installing ZSH through cygwin and then trying to use zsh through Cmder

Tags: command-line, bash, shell, cygwin, zsh

I tried to install Cygwin (64 bit version) on my computer, and it went through hunky-dory until at the very end, autorebase.bat failed with exit code 1. I read through the logs and they weren't too helpful so I tried to run autorebase.bat on my own through a command line and I feel that the issue was Cygwin was trying to run the batch file from the wrong place, so it wasn't able to find dash (in cygwin/bin)

I manually ran autorebase.bat and it went through successfully.

My issue arises when I try to run zsh through the cygwin command prompt. This is what happens

[link to image since I can't post images yet.](http://puu.sh/an4hH/e4fd2e429f.png)

as you can probably tell, the word garble isn't desirable. I have a feeling it's due to zsh not being set up properly, but I don't know how I'd go about fixing it.

The second part is, once I have zsh up and running thanks to you guys, How does one run it through a third-party CLI tool. [like Cmder?](http://bliker.github.io/cmder/)

Whenever I try to start a new cmder window, I set the executable to be zsh, and it runs, but it's missing most of it's commands (ls for example).

Thanks for the help everyone, this is a huge learning experience for me, which is why my request(s) may seem odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

zsh is running properly, but there are syntax differences between bash and zsh for displaying the prompt.

You need to set the PS1 variable to something zsh recognises.

Edit your ~/.zshrc file and add something like

```
export PS1='%m%# '
```

Mine is quite complicated and set to

```
%*%F{green}[%K{black}%B%F{red}R%?%F{blue}S%L%F{magenta}J%j%b%F{green}]%n@%m%f[%!] %F{yellow}%~ %f%k
%#
```

but this may not work for you (depending on your zsh version and terminal type).

Have a look at *EXPANSION OF PROMPT SEQUENCES* in the zsh manual.